# Where to change the registered project name for Android and iOS?

Tags: react-native

In React-Native, I'd like to change below 'registered_name':

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('registered_name', () => test);`

Where should I change this name in Android and iOS files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### index.ios.js & index.android.js

Change the class name

```
 class MyAppName extends React.Component{
```

And the AppRegistry

```
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppName', () => MyAppName);
```

### iOS: /ios/MyAppName/AppDelegate.m

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"MyAppName"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

## Android: /android/appsrc/main/java.com/myappname/MainActivity.java

```
mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyAppName", null);
```